# Gitlab runner not opening application pdf file in chrome browser instead its get downloaded when running ci/cd pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci-runner, pdf-viewer

I am trying to run Selenium automation scripts in headed mode in Gitlab runner in chrome browser ( maven docker image with chrome ), in which we have scenario to open pdf files from application and verify policy related settings.

Pdf files should be opened in chrome browser instead its gets download, so we are unable to test the pdf files.

Is there any settings to be changed in gitlab.yml file or in gitlab runner configuration file.